# Don't understand this Boolean operator logic

Tags: python-2.7, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

```
def odd(x):
    x % 2
    return x > 0
```

Why does my function return True for even numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change it to:

```
x = x % 2
```

to actually update the variable in line 2.

Comment: can you not just `return (x % 2) > 0` ?

Comment: you can (and should), but i did not want to rewrite his program (however simple it is).

Comment: Ok. It makes sense to answer how you did. I was just asking.

Comment: Whopse, added my own answer and didn't even notice his typo (and thus what his question was actually asking). Upvote for you

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working as expected because you are returning "is x greater than 0?" Try with x = -1 and you will see that this is false. The x % 2 part is not doing anything.

I would recommend taking an online course like udacity.com 's intro to computer science to get a better grasp of how basic programming works.